# Getting the current row's rank with Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

In my Laravel 4 app, my `users` table has a `votes` column. I'd like to find the current user's rank. I can already get the top 10 users with `User::orderBy('votes', 'desc')->take(10)`, but I'd like to display the current user's rank below that list. Ideally, this would go something like:

```
Auth::user()->rank('orderBy', 'votes', 'desc');
```

I get the logged in user, I ask for his rank assuming I order the users table by votes.

Does anybody know if there's some way I can do this with Eloquent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although still somewhat hacky you can do it via a custom getter (mutator) in Eloquent.

```php
public function getRankAttribute()
{
    return $this->newQuery()->where('votes', '>=', $this->votes)->count();
}
```

You can then get the users rank as an attribute.

```php
$rank = Auth::user()->rank;
```

Comment: Elegant. Similar hacky solution though. I'll submit a feature request, it's got to be better to use the database's native ability.

Comment: actually, `$this` doesn't seem to be able to access the model's fields inside scope methods, whereas a normal method can.

Comment: It's working for me. You need to do it via the `Auth::user()` so you're actually calling `rank` on that users object. I've just actually tested this though and it appears it doesn't return the count. I've updated my answer to instead be used via a getter. I have tested and can confirm it works.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
$currUser = DB::table('users')->where('votes','>=',Auth::user()->votes)->count();
```

And display `$currUser` by the user details below the top 10 list?

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Clever. Also hacky. I'll leave this un-marked for a day or so to enourage an official solution, but it's workable. Thanks!