# Getting rank of row in OrderBy Eloquent query

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I understand that this seems to be a documented mySQL question. However, I found no Eloquent solution to get the ranks of rows in an orderBy query. Here is what I want.

I have a table that looks like this

```
id | number
-----------
1  | 30
2  | 24
3  | 4
4  | 45
```

I am able to order the number column this query:

```
Number::orderBy('number', 'desc')->get();
```

However, I want to retrieve the rank of each row. So the row that has the id of 4 (with the number of 45) would have a rank of 1. The row with the id of 1 (and the number of 30) would have the rank of 2.

What is the best way to get the rank of a row with Eloquent queries?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343482/getting-the-current-rows-rank-with-laravel

Answer (score 3):

For laravel's Eloquent...
Add this to your model. Unleash the greatness of T.Otwells Eloquent ;)

```
public function getPostionAttribute()
{
    return $this->newQuery()->where('number', '>=', $this->number)->count();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can rely on this (rename row to rank if you like) to get multiple records instead of querying per model:

```
// any Model, model trait or whatever you like
// for convenience wrapped in scope
public function scopeGetWithRowNumber($query, $columns = ['*'])
{
    // Set the row number
    $offset = (int) $query->getQuery()->offset;
    DB::statement(DB::raw("set @row={$offset}"));

    // Adjust SELECT clause to contain the row
    if ( ! count($query->getQuery()->columns)) $query->select($columns);
    $sub = $query->addSelect([DB::raw('@row:=@row+1 as row')]);

    // Return the result instead of builder object
    return $query->get();
}
```

Then use however you'd run any query:

```
Number::getWithRowNumber(); // SELECT * + row attribute starting from 1

Number::take(25)->skip(2500)->getWithRowNumber(); // SELECT * + row 2501+

Number::latest()->getWithRowNumber(['id','number']); // SELECT id, number + row 1+

Number::orderBy('number','desc')->getWithRowNumber(); // example from your question
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's quite simple really, what you currently have will work.

```
$i = 1;
$numbers = Number::orderBy('number', 'desc')->get();

foreach($numbers as $number)
{
    echo $i . ' ' . $number->id;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: I actually did this, but when I implement pagination, the numbers start over from one on the next page.

Comment: Then initialize $i by the offset (`getFrom()` method of pagination) rather than 1.